# Logistic Regression different results with R and Python?

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression

I used a logistic regression approach in both programs, and was wondering why I am getting different results, especially with the coefficients. The outcome, Infection, is (1, 0) and Flushed is a continuous variable.

### Python:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(data['INFECTION'], data['Flushed'])
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

Results:

```
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:              INFECTION   No. Observations:                  414
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                      413
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Fri, 24 Aug 2018   Pseudo R-squ.:                  -1.388
Time:                        15:47:42   Log-Likelihood:                -184.09
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -77.104
                                        LLR p-value:                       nan
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Flushed       -0.6467      0.070     -9.271      0.000      -0.783      -0.510
==============================================================================
```

### R:

```
mylogit <- glm(INFECTION ~ Flushed, data = cvc, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit)
```

Results:

```
Call:
glm(formula = INFECTION ~ Flushed, family = "binomial", data = cvc)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.0598  -0.3107  -0.2487  -0.2224   2.8051  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.91441    0.38639 -10.131  < 2e-16 ***
Flushed      0.22696    0.06049   3.752 0.000175 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: **Please post reproducible code including the dataset URL.**

Comment: Related: [Why are the logistic regression results different between statsmodels and R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558067/why-are-the-logistic-regression-results-different-between-statsmodels-and-r). Please post the rest of the R summary below "Signif. codes:". Did you have the same number of DF? How did you treat factors or dummies? `Df Model: 0 Df Residuals: 413` sounds wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing the constant (offset) parameter in the Python logistic model.

To use R's formula syntax you're fitting two different models:

```
Python model: INFECTION ~ 0 + Flushed
R model     : INFECTION ~ Flushed
```

To add a constant to the Python model use `sm.add_constant(...)`.

Comment: @smci Yes I agree. There might be more things going wrong. But the Python results only show estimates for one parameter, so that's already a difference with the R model results. It'd be easy to check with reproducible data...